# ¿Cómo muestro en pantalla si es mayor de edad?

Tags: php, html

Tengo que mostrar con este `PHP` a la hora de hacer `click` con el botón, el nombre y si la persona es mayor o menor de edad.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> A </title>
</head>
<body>

<form method='GET' action="24.php">

    Nombres:
     <input type="nombres" name="nombre" size="20" maxlength="50">
     <br><br><br>


    Edad:
     <input type="edad" name="edad" size="10" maxlength="20">

     <br><br><br>

 <input type = "submit" value="Mostrar el nombre"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Aquí viene mi `PHP`. El cual no sé si esta correcto

```
echo $_GET['nombres'];

echo $_GET['edad'];

if($_GET['edad']<18)
{
    echo "<H1> $_GET['nombres'] es menor de edad</H1>";
}



?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Algunas correcciones en su código :

- El nombre del `input` es `nombre` en singular y no *nombres*
- No existen los tipo *(type)* de `input` , `nombre` ni `edad`, lo más adecuados serían tipo `text` y `number` , para saber los tipos revise [esta Referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input)
- Para concatenar variables con Texto , lo más sencillo sería usar el operador **`.`**
- Le hace falta la etiqueta de cierre del formulario `</form>`
- Adicionalmente puede validar que el valor de edad sea número , para esto puede emplear la función [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.is-numeric.php)

**HTML**

```
<form method='GET' action="24.php">
   Nombres:
   <input type="text" name="nombre" size="20">
   <br><br>
   Edad:
   <input type="number" name="edad" size="10">
   <br><br>
   <input type = "submit" value="Mostrar el nombre"/>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
    $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
    if(is_numeric($_GET['edad'])){
        if($_GET['edad']< 18)
             echo "<H1> ". $nombre ." es menor de edad</H1>";
        else
             echo "<H1> ". $nombre ." es Mayor de edad</H1>";
     }
    else
       echo "Solo se permiten valores númericos para el campo Edad";
```

Answer (score 0):

Para simplificar el código, puedes usar el *operador ternario*  para hacer la comprobación.

Si en el `input`  indicas el tipo `number` `<input type="number" name="edad" size="10">` considero que la comprobación vía PHP de si es numérico sería redundante.

Mi propuesta es esta:

#### HTML

```
<form method='GET' action="24.php">
   Nombres:
   <input type="text" name="nombre" size="20">
   <br><br>
   Edad:
   <input type="number" name="edad" size="10">
   <br><br>
   <input type = "submit" value="Enviar datos"/>
</form>
```

#### PHP

Usando el [operador ternario](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php) y verificando si los datos del form fueron llenados.

El operador ternario funciona así: si la condición de la izquierda se cumple (`_$GET['edad']<18`), la variable toma el valor indicado a la izquierda de los dos puntos `:`, si no se cumple, tomará el valor indicado a la derecha de los dos puntos.

```
if(isset(_$GET['edad'])){
    $strMensaje = _$GET['edad']<18 ? 'es menor de edad' : 'es mayor de edad';
}else{
    $strMensaje="Edad no especificada en el formulario";
}

if(isset(_$GET['nombre'])){
    echo _$GET['nombre'].$strMensaje;
}else{
    echo "El nombre no fue indicado en el formulario";
}
```